# The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'

Tags: c#, string, dataset, nullable

```
public virtual int Fill(DataSetservices.Jobs_detailsDataTable dataTable, 
    global::System.Nullable<global::System.String> fromdate,     
    global::System.Nullable<global::System.DateTime> todate)
```

I wrote above code in `dataset.xsd` in C#, but it is throwing an error:

> Error 1
>   The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order
>   to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Nullable'

Suggest me how to use string because i want to use string and nothing else

Comment: Use just `global::System.String fromDate`.

Comment: Don't extend the autogenerated `designer.cs` file under the xsd file. Instead create another file with the same name(without designer) and extend the `TableAdapter` classes with the `partial` keyword. That works since the autogenerated classes are also `partial`. The `designer.cs` file will be recreated on the next change in the designer and all of your changes will be lost.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is used to "amplify" a type which cannot hold the `null` value into a type that does. `String` is already a type that can hold the `null` value. Therefore you can't use the combination `Nullable<string>`. (You can read about `Nullable<T>` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). In short just turn your method's prototype into this: `public virtual int Fill((DataSetservices.Jobs_detailsDataTable dataTable, string fromdate, DateTime? todate);`

Comment: Do you have many different types/namespaces called `System`, `Nullable`, `String`, `DateTime` and so on since you use that many [`global` namespace aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)?

Answer (score 18):

`string` is already nullable, because it's a reference type.  You don't need to wrap it in `Nullable` in order to have a null value.  Not only is it not needed, but as per the error message you're getting, it's not even *possible*.  Only non-nullable value types can be used as the generic argument for `Nullable`.

Answer (score 4):

[String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is a class, it not a `struct` like `System.Int32` or other primitive types. It can hold null value. `Nullable<T>`  works with value types.

From the name it appears that you want to store `DateTime` object. Its always better to have `DateTime` in its own type ie. `DateTime`, for Nullable you can use `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs on MSDN about [Nullable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) you will notice that T is constrained with struct. [Constraints on Type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) reveals that such a constraint restricts the generic parameter to being a value type except Nullable<T> (Do note that Nullable<T> is a struct!).

As MSDN docs say, string is a reference type meaning that the generic parameter constraint made for Nullable<T> will invalidate types such as Nullable<string> or with any reference type as generic parameter.