# How can I prevent a string argument changing from null to empty when bound to a parameter?

Tags: string, powershell, parameters, null

Consider the following code:

```
function f {
    param (
        [AllowNull()]
        [string]
        $x
    )
    return $x
}

$r = f -x $null
```

`$null` is converted to `[string]::Empty` by the time `return` is reached.  `$null` is different from `[string]::Empty` and I'd like to preserve this distinction.  I'd also prefer to keep `$x` as type `[string]` because `$x` only has meaning as a string and the interface is used elsewhere.

1. How can I make `$x` come out as `$null` when it is passed `$null`?
2. Is there some other way I can tell that `$x` was passed `$null` *not* `[string]::Empty` from inside `f`?

---

**Update 1**

What I am trying to do works for other types.  Here is the same concept for `[int]`:

```
function f { 
    param( 
        [System.Nullable[int]]$x 
    )
    return $x 
}

$r = f -x $null
```

In that case `$r` is indeed `$null`.  `$x` can be either `$null` or `[int]` but nothing else.  It seems strange to me to have to allow *any* object just so I can pass a `$null` or `[int]`.

`[System.Nullable[string]]` produces an error that boils down to `[System.Nullable[T]]` requires that `[T]` is a value type.  `[string]` is a reference type, so that doesn't work.

---

**Update 2**

It seems to be possible to pass `$null` without causing conversion to a parameter of any type *except* `[string]`.  I've tested the following:

```
function f { param([System.Nullable[int]]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Nullable[System.DayOfWeek]]$x) $x }
function f { param([hashtable]$x) $x }
function f { param([array]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int]]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Collections.ArrayList]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Collections.BitArray]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Collections.SortedList]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Collections.Queue]$x) $x }
function f { param([System.Collections.Stack]$x) $x }
```

Passing `$null` to any of these functions outputs $null.  The *only* parameter type I haven't found a way to which to pass `$null` without conversion is `[string]`.

---

**Update 3**

PowerShell's behavior in this regard is also inconsistent with C#.  The corresponding function in C# is as follows:

```
public string f(string x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Calling `f(null)` returns `null`.

---

**Update 4**

[Apparently `[NullString]::Value` was intended to address this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38959755/1404637)  I seems to work to pass `null` to `string` parameters in C# APIs.  However, `[NullString]::Value` gets converted to `[string]::empty` in PowerShell the same as `$null`.  Consider the following code:

```
function f {
    param (
        [AllowNull()]
        [string]
        $x
    )
    return $x
}

$r = f -x ([NullString]::Value)
$r.GetType().Name
```

Executing that code outputs `String`. `$r` is `[string]::Empty` despite that `[NullString]::Value` was passed to `$x`.

---

**Update 5**

[The PowerShell team has indicated that this was by design](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616#issuecomment-323530442):

> This is by design and ... changing the behavior would be a massive breaking change.

That thread involved an interesting discussion about the reasoning behind it.  I suspect that some of ramifications of this behavior were not understood when the decision was made as the behavior directly contravenes [PowerShell cmdlet "Strongly Encouraged Design Guideline" SD03](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx#SD03) which reads in part as follows:

> If your parameter needs to differentiate between 3 values: $true, $false and “unspecified”, then define a parameter of type Nullable. The need for a 3rd, "unspecified" value typically occurs when the cmdlet can modify a Boolean property of an object. In this case "unspecified" means to not change the current value of the property.

Comment: You're casting the parameter into a string with [string] before $x

Comment: Exactly. If you don't want something cast to a string: don't cast it to a string.

Comment: [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) [doesn't work for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18852751/1630171), because the type itself is already nullable (in principle). The problem you're facing is that PowerShell casts a `$null` value to a string when passing it to the parameter, which auto-converts the value to an empty string.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I agree.  The conversion to `[string]::empty` seems like strange behavior when both `[AllowNull()]` and `[string]` are present.

Comment: In your update you're using an int, which can have an null value. A string cannot be null, it can only be empty. So the `[System.Nullable]` is allowed for the int.

Comment: @JasonSnell _"A string cannot be null, it can only be empty."_   I don't think that's an accurate generalization. It's not true for class members, for example. If you instantiate `class c { [string]$x }`, `x` is `$null` not `[string]::Empty`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize and complement the information from the question, answers, and comments:

**tl;dr**:

**It's best not to fight PowerShell's design of not allowing `[string]` variables to be `$null`, and to limit use of `[NullString]::Value` to calls to .NET methods.**

---

- **PowerShell converts `$null` to `''` (the empty string) when it is assigned to `[string]`-typed [parameter] variables, and *parameter* variables also *default* to  `''`.**

  - The only *exception* is the use of *uninitialized* `[string]` *properties* in PSv5+ custom classes, as alxr9 (the OP) points out: `class c { [string] $x }; $null -eq ([c]::new()).x` indeed yields `$True` implying that property `.x` contains `$null`. However, this exception is likely *accidental* and [probably a bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7294), given that when you initialize the property with `$null` or assign `$null` to it later, the conversion to `''` again kicks in; similarly, using `return $null` from a `[string]`-typed *method* outputs `''`.
  - The exception aside, PowerShell's behavior differs from *C#* string variables / parameters, to which you *can* assign / pass `null` directly, and which default to `null` in certain contexts. `string` is a .NET *reference type*, and this behavior applies to all reference types.
    (Since reference type instances can inherently contain `null`, there is no need for a separate nullable wrapper via `` System.Nullable`1 ``, which is indeed not supported (it works for *value types* only).)
- As noted in the question (update 5), PowerShell's departure from C#'s behavior is by (design, and it's [changing it is not an option](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616#issuecomment-323530442) for reasons of backward compatibility alone.
- **`[NullString]::Value`** was introduced in v3 specifically to **allow passing `null` to `string` parameters of *.NET methods*** - and while use in pure PowerShell code wasn't explicitly discouraged or prevented, the unexpected behavior in update 4 and the comments by a core PowerShell team member (see below) suggest that such uses weren't anticipated.

  - **Caveat**: While it *is* possible to use `[NullString]::Value` in pure *PowerShell code*, there may be pitfalls beyond the one discussed below, given that **use of `[NullString]::Value` was never intended outside the context of calling .NET methods**; to [quote a core member of the PowerShell team](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616#issuecomment-323597003):

> Parameters to C# methods was the target scenario for `[NullString]::Value`, and I will say that might be the only reasonable scenario.

- A **workaround** is to **type your (parameter) variable as `[object]`** or to **not type-constrain it** at all, which amounts to the same. Such variables happily accept `$null`, but note that **you may have to stringify (convert to `[string]`) non-`$null` values yourself** (although PowerShell does that for you automatically in explicit or implied string contexts) - see the penultimate code example below.

---

**If, despite the advice above, you do need a `[string]` parameter variable that you can pass `$null` to via `[NullString]::Value`**, as in update 4 in your question, there is an - obscure - **workaround** for [the optimization bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4312) that prevents your code from working, thanks to sleuthing by [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral):

```
function f {
    param (
        [string] $x
    )
    # Workaround; without this, even passing [NullString]::Value 
    # returns '' rather than $null            
    if ($False) { Remove-Variable } 
    return $x
}

$r = f -x ([NullString]::Value)
$r.GetType().Name  # now fails, because $r is $null
```

Note that when assigning / passing `[NullString]::Value` to a `[string]`-typed [parameter] variable, it is *instantly* converted to `$null` (in the case of a *parameter* variable, only if the bug gets fixed or with the workaround in place).
However, once `$null` has been successfully stored in the variable this way, it can apparently be passed around as such (again, only if the bug gets fixed or with the workaround in place).

---

If you don't want to rely on the workaround / wait for the fix and/or don't want to burden the caller with having to pass `[NullString]::Value` instead of `$null`, you can build on the answers by [Curios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720406/45375) and [Jason Schnell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720334/45375), which rely on **using an *untyped* (implicitly `[object]`-typed) or explicitly `[object]`-typed parameter, which *can* accept `$null` as-is**:

```
function f {
    param (
        [AllowNull()] # Explicitly allow passing $null.
                      # Note: Strictly speaking only necessary with [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        $x # Leave the parameter untyped (or use [object]) so as to retain $null as-is
    )

    # Convert $x to a type-constrained [string] variable *now*:
    if ($null -eq $x) {
        # Make $x contain $null, despite being [string]-typed
        [string] $x = [NullString]::Value
    } else {
        # Simply convert any other type to a string.
        [string] $x = $x
    }

    # $x is now a bona fide [string] variable that can be used
    # as such even in .NET method calls.

    return $x
}
```

It's somewhat cumbersome, but enables the caller to pass `$null` directly (or any string, or a type of any other instance that will be converted to a string).

A slight down-side is that this approach doesn't allow you to define positional parameters in the same position via different parameter sets that are selected by the parameters' *specific* types.

---

Finally, it's worth mentioning that **if it's sufficient to detect when a (non-mandatory) parameter was *omitted*, you can check `$PSBoundParameters`**:

```
function f {
    param (
        [string] $x
    )

    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('x')) { # Was a value passed to parameter -x?
        "-x argument was passed: $x"
    } else {
        "no -x argument passed."
    }
}
```

As stated, this only works for the *omission* case (and therefore doesn't work for *mandatory* parameters at all). If you pass `$null`, the usual conversion to `''` kicks in, and you won't be able to distinguish between passing `$null` and `''`.
(Though if you added the above workaround / waited for the bug fix, you could again pass `[NullString]::Value` to effectively pass `$null`, or even use `[NullString]::Value` as the parameter *default value*.)

Comment: [NullString]::Value did the trick!  I had to pass a true NULL to an external function that differentiated between NULL and an empty string.  Never realized Powershell botched strings like this.

Answer (score 3):

By default, [string] assigns default value as `[string]::Empty`, so the parameter definition will convert it whenever enters function f.
a. You can change the parameter as `[object]$x`

```
[object]$newparamnull -eq $null
[string]$newparamstring -eq [string]::Empty
```

b. The previous change will do the job:

```
function f {
    param (
        [AllowNull()]
        [object]
        $x)
   if($x -eq $null) {
      write-output "null" 
   }
   elseif($x -eq [string]::empty){
      write-output "empty"
   } 
   else {"other"}
}
```

Test:

```
f -x $null
f -x [string]::empty
f -x "aaa"
```

Comment: _"By default, [string] assigns default value as [string]::Empty"_ I don't think that's an accurate generalization.  It's not true for classes, for example.  If you instantiate `class c { [string]$x }`, `x` is `$null` not `[string]::Empty`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function f {
    param (
        [AllowNull()]$x
    )
    return $x
}

$r = f -x $null
```

By removing the `[string]` and using `[AllowNull()]` the above function will now allow you to pass in a null object or an empty string. You can check for the type using `$x.GetType` with an if statement and determining if `$x` is null or an empty string.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the parameter is either `$null` or a string you could validate the parameter: `[ValidateScript($_ -eq $null -or $_ -is [string])]`. You could also cast non-null parameter values to string in the body, but that might yield undesired results (e.g. when the string representation of an object is its type rather than its value).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You should make that comment an answer.  It's far and away the most helpful suggestion yet.

Comment: Nah. This answer already resolves the root problem. I merely suggested some fine-tuning.

Comment: FWIW PowerShell throws an exception when you pass `$null` to a parameter with the `[ValidateScript()]` attribute.  It looks parameter validation would have to take place in the body.