# Class member is json-serialized as empty string instead of null

Tags: powershell

I'm using the `class` keyword in a powershell script.

I want to serialize instances of my custom class, but I observe that `$null` members are serialized as `""` instead of `null`.

Reproduction:

```
Class foo{
    [string]$X
}

[foo]@{ x = $null } | ConvertTo-Json

$foo = New-Object foo
$foo.X = $null

$foo | ConvertTo-Json
```

Outputs :

```
{
    "X":  ""
}
{
    "X":  ""
}
```

But I'm expecting :

```
{
    "X":  null
}
{
    "X":  null
}
```

As a side note, this works :

```
@{ X = $null } | ConvertTo-Json
```

It outputs expected :

```
{
    "X":  null
}
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

PS: if it matters `$PSVersionTable` outputs:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                     
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.546                                                                                                                                                             
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                   
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.546                                                                                                                                                            
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                           
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: No, there's no way to fix that due to the way PowerShell implements typing - assignment to a variable that has been type-cast `[string]` will never result in `$null`, always an empty string

Comment: If you are able to use 3rd party libraries for this project you could also check out NewtonSoft. I think it's kind of the industry standard in .NET for dealing with json and you get a lot more control of the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64465331/45375) explains the problem well**: if you assign `$null` to a `[string]` typed property or variable, you'll end up with `''` (the empty string).

There is an - obscure - **workaround**, which assumes that you have control over the values you assign:

You can **assign `[NullString]::Value`** to a `[string]`-type-constrained variable or property to make it store a `$null` value:

```
Class foo {
  # Default to $null
  [string] $X = [NullString]::Value
}

[foo]::new() | ConvertTo-Json

[foo] @{ X = [NullString]::Value } | ConvertTo-Json

($o = New-Object foo).X = [NullString]::Value
$o | ConvertTo-Json
```

Note:

- **The primary purpose of [`[NullString]::Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString.Value) is to allow passing true `null` (`$null`) values to `string`-typed parameters of *.NET Methods***, which wouldn't work when passing `[string]`-typed PowerShell variables or properties, which on assignment invariably convert `$null` to `''` (the empty string), as explained in Mathias' answer.
- **While you can use it in pure PowerShell code as well, as shown above, be mindful that other code that accepts `[string]`-typed values may not expect them to ever be `$null`**, and that passing a value to another `[string]`-constrained (parameter) variable again converts to `''`.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354791/45375) for more information.

The above yields:

```json
{
  "X": null
}
{
  "X": null
}
{
  "X": null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to fix this ?

## No

([a workaround exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64465752/712649) depending on the level of control you have over the input, but there's no way to assign `$null` directly to a `[string]`-typed PowerShell class property)

Runtime typing enforcement in PowerShell classes doesn't rely on .NET's implicit type conversion rules - this is offloaded to PowerShell's existing language infrastructure and the conversion logic found there instead, and the default type converter for `[string]` *always* returns an instance, never null.

You can observe the same behavior when typing variables:

```
Remove-Variable X -Force

# Let's assign $null to a variable with no type constraints
$X = $null
# True - we can assign $null to a variable without type constraints just fine
$null -eq $X

# Let's apply a type constraint and assign `$null` again
[string]$X = $null
# False - actual value assigned after type constraint applied is not $null anymore
$null -eq $X
# True - PowerShell has converted $null to ''
'' -eq $X
```

So you have to type `$X` as something other than a string (`[object]` for example) if you want it to retain `$null` values