# Object-Property assigned $null does not test true for $null

Tags: powershell

I've started using PowerShell to get some things done and played with the variable `$null` in PowerShell.

I've encountered the problem that when I assign the variable `$null` to a variable defined in a class, the test returns `false` not `true`.

Example Code:

```
class test {
    [string]$test1
}

$test = [test]::new()

$test.test1 = $null

$null -eq $test2 # tests true

$null -eq $test.test1 # tests false
```

Now the test of the undefinded variable `$test2` returns `true` as every undefined variable in PowerShell is assigned `$null`.

But if I test the property `test1` of the object `test` which I assigned `$null` tests `false` for `$null`

Is it because in PowerShell `$null` is an object with the value `$null` and now the property of the object is not `$null` as it has the object `$null` assigned to it with an empty value?

I've read into the docs of Microsoft ["Everything you wanted to know about $null"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.1), but it does not enlighten me.

If I do not initialize the variable, then it will test `true` for `$null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$test.test1` is not `$null`, it's empty string (because you explicitely defined it's value to be `[string]`):

```
C:\> $test.test1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Proof:

```
C:\> $test.test1 -eq ""
True
```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on [robdy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322713/45375):

- **By design, `[string]`-typed variables, parameter variables, and custom-class properties in PowerShell do not store `$null`**<sup>[1]</sup>, only actual string values. **Assigning `$null` always converts to `''`** (the empty string).

  - Below, `$var` receives `''`, not `$null`, due to being `[string]`-typed; therefore, the first `-eq` test fails and the second succeeds.
  - `[string] $var = $null; $null -eq $var; '' -eq $var`
  - Note that *other* .NET reference types (as opposed to value types, which fundamentally cannot be null) are *not* affected in PowerShell; that is, you *can* assign `$null` to them. Notably, this also applies to `[object]`. Note that *not* type-constraining a variable / parameter / property is the same as `[object]`-typing it.
- **That an *uninitialized* `[string]` *property*  in a PowerShell `class` nonetheless currently defaults to `$null` should be considered a *bug*** - see [GitHub issue #7294](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7294).

  - The inconsistency becomes obvious if you explicitly initialize to `$null`, which again converts to `''` and makes the test fail.
  - `class test { [string]$test1=$null }; $null -eq [test]::new().test1`
  - Should the bug be fixed and you truly need a `$null` value in a `[string]`-typed property - which is ill-advised in the  context of PowerShell code - you'd have to use `[NullString]::Value`, as shown in the answer linked to below:
    `class test { [string]$test1 = [NullString]::Value }; $null -eq [test]::new().test1`

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354791/45375).

---

<sup>[1] The inability to store `$null` is a limitation that *PowerShell* imposes, in the interest of simplification. The underlying .NET type, [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String), typically does not have this limitation in other languages, notably not in C#.</sup>

Comment: that was one thing that got my attention. But i thought that it would be like that, because you did not initialize the variable and so it does not have the type constraint or anything as it is `$null`. As in following example:
````class test {
    [string]$test1
}

$test = [test]::new()

$test.test1

$null -eq $test2 # tests true

$null -eq $test.test1 # tests true

$test.test1 | gm #comes back with an error "gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet"````

Comment: @toodumbtocode, it's an inconsistency that I'm hoping they'll fix. Note that in a _parameter variable_ the same lack of initialization does result in `''`, as in regular variables; e.g., `& { param([string] $test1) $null -eq $test1 }` yields `$false`. Should the inconsistency be removed and you truly need a `$null` value - which is ill-advised in the  context of PowerShell code - you'd have to use `[NullString]::Value`, as shown in the linked answer: `class test { [string]$test1 = [NullString]::Value } $null -eq [test]::new().test1`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `type contstraint` like `[string]` or `[int]` Powershell initializes members at `null`-assignment with the default of the contrained type.

As @robdy states in above answer you've either check for the types default value or remove the constraint.

This may become more obvious if you're using a `[int]` type contstraint:

```
class test {
    [int]$i1 = 42
}
    
$test = [test]::new()
Write-Host $test.i1
$test.i1 = $null
Write-Host $test.i1
```

Output:

```
42
0
```