# How does one use the Try-Catch-Finally block in a class method?

Tags: powershell, class-method, try-catch-finally

I get contradictory error messages when trying to set up a `try-catch-finally` block in a class method which returns a string.

My code is:

```
class exampleClass {    
    [string]Create() {
        try {
            $rsa_Base64 = "string"            
            return $rsa_Base64
        }
        catch {
            {...}
        }
        finally {
            Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP\test.txt
        }        
    }
}
```

In this situation I get the error: `Not all code path returns value within method.`

If I move the `return` statement to the `finally` block I get the error: `Flow of control cannot leave a Finally block.`

I want to add the `finally` block in order to ensure the removal of created files in the `try` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ***avoid* the problem** by using the `return` statement *unconditionally*, outside the `try` / `catch`/ `finally` statement:

```
class exampleClass {    
    [string]Create() {
        $rsa_Base64 = ''  # must initialize the variable
        try {
            $rsa_Base64 = "string"            
        }
        catch {
            {...}
        }
        finally {
            Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP\test.txt
        }
        return $rsa_Base64
    }
}
```

<sup>Note the use of `''` to initialize the variable; using `$null` would ultimately not be effective, because the method is `[string]`-typed, and PowerShell doesn't support `$null` in `[string]` values and converts them to `''` (the empty string) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327734/45375) for more information.</sup>

---

**More properly**, however, you should **ensure that your `catch` branch contains a scope-exiting flow-control statement as well**<sup>[1]</sup>, namely [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Return) or [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) (while `exit` technically works too, it should only be used in *script files*, as it exits the session as a whole):

```
class exampleClass {    
    [string]Create() {
        try {
            $rsa_Base64 = "string"            
            return $rsa_Base64
        }
        catch {
            {...}
            return ''  # must exit the method from this block too 
        }
        finally {
            Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP\test.txt
        }        
    }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, the `finally` block not only doesn't *need* a scope-exiting statement, by design it *doesn't support any*. The reason is that this block is run outside the normal flow of control and is intended solely for cleanup.</sup>