# Searching through large Powershell arrays

Tags: powershell, collections, null, filtering

Warning: Powershell novice, terms/code may be incorrect

Say I have a Powershell array with data from Invoke-Sqlcmd, say 10,000 "rows" with a half dozen (Col1-Col6) columns each. Say I want to find every row with an empty Col5. Right now I'm doing

```
foreach ($row in $sqlimport.col1)
 { $col5data = $sqlimport.Where({$_.col1 -eq $row}) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Col5
if ( '' -eq $col5data ) {$col5data+1} else {} $col5data
```

Returns 1, which it should in my test. Code seems wrong and slow. It takes several minutes to run through. When something like

```
$sqlimport.Where({$_.col5 -eq 'somedatathatisthere'})
```

takes milliseconds

However,

```
$sqlimport.Where({$_.col5 -eq ''})
```

Returns blank

```
($sqlimport.Where({$_.col5 -eq ''})).Count
```

Returns 0

Comment: Maybe you could do this in sql.

Comment: Might be worth trying `group-object` I have found this useful in certain tasks when working with large data sets. Please try `($sqlimport | Group-Object col5 | Where {$_.name -eq ""}).group` should output all entries where col5 is blank, however you should have another field to reference which row is blank (ideally a key or something).

Comment: @mklement0 '' -eq doesn't work, but '' -like does. GetType() says String System.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're asking PowerShell to create an array consisting of all the values in column `col1`, and then for each iteration you search *the entire array again* to find the corresponding `col5` value. That's entirely unnecessary.

Simply loop over the array itself:

```
foreach($row in $sqlimport){
    if($row.Col5 -like ''){
        Write-Host "Col5 is empty in row with id $($row.Col1)"
    }
}
```

This only iterates over the entire array *once*.

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71592438/45375) explains the problem with the inefficiency of your *first* attempt well and offers a solution that ultimately performs best, due to use of a (single) [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement* (as opposed to the much slower [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*).

However, **a solution using a (single) [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) call** (or the related [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) method):

- is only *slightly* slower<sup>[1]</sup>
- while being more concise and arguably conceptually more elegant.

It is what you tried with `$sqlimport.Where({ $_.col5 -eq '' })`, which, based on your feedback, requires only one small tweak to make it work:

- Instead of `-eq ''` **use `-like ''`**, which is a somewhat obscure<sup>[2]</sup> shortcut to **testing for an empty string (`''`) *and also* for a `$null` value** (as also used in Mathias' answer) - it is, in essence, the **equivalent of .NET's [`[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.IsNullOrEmpty) method**.

```sh
# -like matches both '' and $null
$sqlimport.Where({ $_.col5 -like '' })
```

Note:

- If you wanted **to test for `$null` values *only***, use the following; note how `$null` is placed on the *LHS*, which is generally advisable for robust comparisons<sup>[3]</sup>:

  ```sh
  $sqlimport.Where({ $null -eq $_.col5 })
  ```

  - As an aside: [GitHub issue #10656](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10656) proposes introducing a simplified test for `$null` with something like `-is $null`; unfortunately, the associated PR has been abandonded.
- As an aside: `[string]`-type-constrained *PowerShell variables* never store `$null` values: 
  `[string] $str = $null` causes `$str` to contain `''`, not `$null`. However, `[string]`-typed *property values* not populated in PowerShell code *can* contain `$null` values, as in your case.

  - For passing a true `$null` value to a `string`-typed *.NET API* in PowerShell code, a *special singleton* must be used (passing `$null` directly would again result in `''):` [NullString]::Value`
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354791/45375) for background information.

---

<sup>[1] For a **performance comparison** of PowerShell's various enumeration (iteration) features, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] The real purpose of the [`-like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) is to perform [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-expression matching. The shortcut relies on 
`-like` - which operates on (non-null) *strings* only - auto-converting non-string operands to strings, which in the case of `$null` causes conversion to `''` (the *empty string*).</sup>

<sup>[3] To reliably test for `$null`, place it on the *LHS* of an `-eq` / `-ne` operation; e.g., `$null -eq $var`. If you place `$null` on the RHS - `$var -eq $null` - and `$var` happens to be a *collection* (such as an array), the return value is the *array of matching elements*, i.e. the array of those *elements* in `$var` whose value is `$null`, which is a different operation - see [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq-and--ne).</sup>